# RxJS toArray() equivalent

Tags: rxjs

consider following scenario:
Array of values shall be processed one after another and after processing once again single array value shall be returned. Following code will do the trick:

```
Observable.of([1, 2, 3, 4]) /* Base array */
.concatMap<number[], number[]>(valArr => { /* Inner stream to process array */
  return Observable.from(valArr) /* breake apart array into values */
  .map<number, number>((num, idx) => {
    return valArr[idx] + 1; 
  })
  .toArray()
})
.subscribe(arr => {
  console.log(arr)
})
```

I.e. will decompose stream into single element stream, do some operations on values and `toArray()` will merge it back to array response. Whole further processing is stopped until internal `concatMap` processing single element is not completed.

The question is, how to achieve same behavior without `toArray()` usage?

Comment: You may use reduce to achieve the same goal, but that may not be an improvement in the code.

Comment: Copy the source code of the operator directly into your code. Et voila, same behavior, but you're not using the operator anymore.

Comment: @IngoBürk I have to mark your comment as delete candidate, because it does not bring any value to question and undermines it's seriousness

Comment: No, it demonstrates the absurdness of the question. You have code that works perfectly fine, and any other solution will have the same effect by definition. So what's the point here?

Comment: I see no point of calling question "absurd" or judging it's validity according to your personal opinion just because for you it seems not reasonable to explore it. As question is correctly formatted, not offensive, not a duplicate and just tries to answer question "how to do this manually" I see no valid reason to provide this kind of answer. Anyway, still thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I haven't provided any answer. I wrote a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using `Observable.from()` on your baseArray and skipping the concatMap//inner observable logic. If you want to end up with an array your best option is indeed to use `.toArray()` at the end:

```
Observable.from([])
  .map((val) => 1 + val)
  .toArray()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `toArray` is operator we need to avoid due to some complicated exception handling on stream. But hey, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

We just come up with following workarounds:

Using concat:

```
Observable.of([1, 2, 3, 4]) /* Base array */
.concatMap<number[], number[]>(valArr => { /* Inner stream to process array */


  return Observable.from(valArr) /* breake apart array into values */
  .map<number, number>((num, idx) => {
    return valArr[idx] + 1; 
  })
  .concat(Observable.from(valArr))
})
.subscribe(arr => {
  console.log(arr)
})
```

Using last:

```
Observable.of([1, 2, 3, 4]) /* Base array */
.concatMap<number[], number[]>(valArr => { /* Inner stream to process array */

  return Observable.from(valArr) /* breake apart array into values */
  .map<number, number>((num, idx) => {
    return valArr[idx] + 1; 
  })
  .last()
  .map(v => {
    return Observable.from(valArr)
  })
})
.subscribe(arr => {
  console.log(arr)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4])
          .reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr + 1], [])

// result: [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.